# React - Set state work only in async operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tsx

I'm using React (with TypeScript), and I found out very strange behavior.
In the method "handleAnswer" I'm changing the variable "isReady" and also printing the value using the useEffect hook. but the change only takes place if I put a timer there, When I took the timer out the variable stopped changing, and I stopped seeing the output in the console. What am I doing wrong?

```js
export const App = () => {

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(true);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);


  useEffect(() => { console.log(isReady) },[isReady]);
  
  
  const handleAnswer = async (isLiked: boolean) => {
    setIsReady(false);

    // WHEN I REMOVE THIS LINE, IT DOESN'T WORK
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));

    setCounter(counter + 1)
    setIsReady(true);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App" >

    { isReady ? <div className="main-content"></div> :<CircularProgress /> }

    <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => handleAnswer(true)} startIcon={<ThumbUpIcon />}>
      click
    </Button>
   </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: It seems you think `setIsReady(false);` updates state instantly, then `setCounter(counter + 1)` sets state instantly, then `setIsReady(true);` updates state instantly. React state updates are async, these state updates are queued for the next render, so `setIsReady` should only be called once per render with whatever value you want it to have on the next render. As you're caling it here, it's just resetting it to true again and again. What behavior are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: **Closely** related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) and countless others about React state updates. But not ***quite*** a duplicate (or so it seemed to me, opinions may vary). Maybe there's a better dupetarget though.

Comment: @ggorlen I need this behavior to control a scroll loader, how else can I do it?

Comment: Please provide more details about that scroll loader (i.e. minimal code). How you do these things is use-case specific.

Comment: @ggorlen I edited the question and added the relevant code

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea how to help. What is the behavior supposed to be like, at a high level? This feels like stub code. Maybe an explanation like "I'm making an infinite scroll component. When the user clicks on a button at the bottom of the div, I'm fetching an array of new items from an API and appending them to the div, making the button inactive and showing a loader while the items are being fetched, but it's not working because the loader shows even after the items were fetched", or something like that.

Comment: The answer already provided explains why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing, but it probably doesn't help you actually implement whatever you want to implement because it's unclear what that is. I don't see any scroll listeners or scrolling-related behavior, so I'm not sure how to connect that to the "scroll loader" you mention.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm using the `CircularProgress` component from Material-UI (this is the scroll loader). and you can see a condition there, that if `isReady` is true, I want to show to scroll loader, and if it's false to show other content. Now, when you click on the button it should show the scroll loader until the function ends. I'm using the `isReady` flag just to control the scroll loader.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm sorry I probably used the wrong term, When I say "scroll loader" I just mean a simple loader animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State updates are **queued** and processed as a batch after the code that queued them has returned. So without the promise, your `handleAnswer` code does this:

1. Queues a state update changing `isReady` to `false`.
2. Queues a state update adding to `counter`.
3. Queues a state update changing `isReady` to `true`.

React does those three updates once your code has returned, so they only trigger a single re-render, and during that re-render `isReady` has the same value it had the last time the dependencies on your `useEffect` were checked, so the `useEffect` callback doesn't run.

*With* the promise, your code does this:

1. Queues a state update changing `isReady` to `false`.
2. Yields back waiting for a promise to settle.
3. Once the promise settles:

   1. Queues a state update adding to `counter`.
   2. Queues a state update changing `isReady` to `true`.

Between #2 and #3 on that list, React has a chance to process state changes, and so it does — triggering a re-render when `isReady` is `false`, which triggers your `useEffect` callback because `isReady` has a different value than the last time the dependencies were checked. Then later, after the promise settles, your code queues a couple of other state changes, which trigger another render, triggering your `useEffect` callback again.

The key points are:

- State updates are not immediate
- State updates are *batched*
- Even if the state changed and then changed back, if there was no render between those changes, the `useEffect` callback triggered by a the value being different won't run, because the value isn't different by the time it's checked

---

In a comment you've asked:

> So I can achieve this behavior without using promise? I need the `isReady` flag to control a scroll loader until the function is done handling some data synchronously.

If the processing is *synchronous*, it will tie up the main thread that handles UI updates, and your loading indicator may well not be animated (it definitely won't be if the animation is done with JavaScript; if it's an animated GIF or similar, whether it's done depends on the browser and whether all frames are already loaded; if it's a CSS animation, a quick test with Chrome and Firefox suggests that they, at least, *will* keep animating when the processing is happening, but no guarantees).

If you can avoid synchronous processing on the main thread, I would. Consider sending the work to a [worker thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), for instance.

To do it, though, you'll need to change `isReady`, then wait to start the synchronous processing until *after* the result of that change has been rendered by waiting for a `useEffect` callback.

Here's an example using a CSS spinner I found [here](https://github.com/jlong/css-spinners).

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(true);

    // On click, set `isReady` to false
    const startProcessing = () => {
        setIsReady(false);
    };

    // When `isReady` becomes false, start "processing".
    // (You may want to have an instance variable [via a ref]
    // to tell you whether to actually do processing, and if
    // so what to process.)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isReady) {
            // Start "processing"
            const done = Date.now() + 3000;
            while (Date.now() < done) {
                // Busy wait -- NEVER DO THIS IN REAL-WORLD CODE
            }
            // Done "processing"
            setIsReady(true);
        }
    }, [isReady]);

    return <div>
        <input type="button" onClick={startProcessing} value="Start Processing (Takes 3 Seconds)" />
        <div>isReady = {String(isReady)}</div>
        {isReady ? null : <div className="spinner-loader" />}
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
/*
Credit: jlong  @github
Source: https://github.com/jlong/css-spinners
*/
@-moz-keyframes spinner-loader {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner-loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner-loader {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* :not(:required) hides this rule from IE9 and below */
.spinner-loader:not(:required) {
  -moz-animation: spinner-loader 1500ms infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-loader 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner-loader 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.3) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a great explanation, it becomes clear now. so I can achieve this behavior without using promise? I need the`isReady` flag to control a scroll loader until the function is done handling some data synchronously.

Comment: @dev3dev - I've added to the end of the answer.